# hash key invalid for Facebook after app put on play store

Tags: android, facebook, hash

i am trying to put login button in my app , it's work competently .
But as soon i put on playstore after some time it's show : hash key invalid

i also Generate Released hash key for facebook using :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But yet, it can't work

Comment: You have forgotten to generate a key hash for your production key. Sign your app with the key you used to upload to Play store and generate a hash for that key as well. Add this to your Facebook key hash on Facebook developer console.

Comment: Also make sure in Facebook Developer in Status and Review section you have enabled the app for public

Comment: but is there any possibility to invalid key that i always generate keystore through my real mobile devices ?. in some artical i read that always generate keystore from emulator. is it true?